# Select Radio Button using Robot framework is not working

Tags: python, automation, radio-button, robotframework

```
Select Radio Button    question2Answer    question2Answer
```

It is not correct, the system prompts the error message "Element not interactable: element has zero size"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32csw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to wait until the element is ready. That translates into using e.g. keyword [`Wait Until Element Is Enabled`](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Is%20Enabled) like so:

```
Wait Until Element Is Enabled    name:question2Answer
```